# Set visibility in pure-python Cython code

Tags: python, cython

one of my major problems with cython *cdef classes* is that all their variables are by default private. When I am converting some python code to pure-python-mode cython, I have to manually use
`var_name = cython.declare(type, visibility='public)` for every variable.

Is it possible to set all *cdef class* variables to be public by default? If not, do you consider it a good idea, perhaps for feature request?

Answer (score 0):

Not that immediately springs to mind, but you need to do this with a lot of variables you could just make a wrapper like:

```
import functools
declare_public = functools.partial(Cython.declare, visibility='public')
```

Comment: I don't think that works with `cython.declare`; `cython.declare` is compile-time magic.

Comment: (Or at least, it's compile-time magic when Cython compiles the code. I don't think that magic is supported through `functools.partial`.)

Comment: You maybe right, I haven't tested that.  (If it doesn't work it would be nice if it did though, albeit tricky.)  I mean it works *as pure Python* but perhaps not at compile time.

Comment: Even if it worked, it's just a few characters better :(. I would prefer something like `# cython: default_visibility=public` and `i: int = 0`